# Create checkbox that controls 2 hidden radio inputs

Tags: html, jquery, css

Problem:
I have 2 radios which is for "opt-in" and "don't opt-in" for a customer club, in the cart-page. By default nothing is selected on page-load.

How can I turn these radio buttons into 1 single checkbox which can be toggled? My plan is to hide the 2 radio buttons from the page, and have a checkbox which toggles/controls these. On page load, the "don't opt-in" radio has to be checked by default(today, nothing is selected). I managed to solve this by using jquery on page-load and run the function multiple times UNTIL the code has ran 1 time.
I guess to solve it, on click, it needs to change the 'for' attribute to the one from the correct original radio button. Or, any other ideas how to solve this? I'm a beginner in jQuery so I don't have a lot of ideas...
Also, I cannot change the HTML, I can only add HTML, CSS and script to the source code, but not alter the original one.

This is the HTML from the source code(can't alter this):

```
    <div class="bember-register">
        <h3>
            <span>Bli medlem og få medlemspris!</span>
        </h3>
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="bember-register" id="agreeMembershipRadio" data-bind="checked: isRegister, checkedValue: 1" value="1" checked="checked">
            <label for="agreeMembershipRadio">
                <span>
                    <span>Jeg er/vil bli medlem av klubben og får medlemsrabatt på et stort utvalg av varer.</span>
                </span>
            </label>
            <span>
                <a href="#" class="action show-terms-popup" data-bind="if: isTermsAvailable">
                    <span>Se vilkår.</span>
                </a>
                <span data-bind="ifnot: isTermsAvailable"></span>
                <span>Fullfør registering på SMS etter kjøp.</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="bember-register" id="skipMembershipRadio" data-bind="checked: isRegister, checkedValue: 0" value="0">
            <label for="skipMembershipRadio">
                <span>
                    <span>Jeg vil ikke bli medlem av klubben.</span>
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is what I did to make it select one radio button on load:

```
    function hideRadio(){
        if(notRunYet){
          setTimeout(function(){
            $('#skipMembershipRadio').attr('checked', 'checked');
            $('#skipMembershipRadio').click();
            notRunYet=false;
            console.log('runComplete');
          }, 500);
        }
      }
```

Adding this jQuery, selects the first radiobutton which does not opt-in to the customer club.

How can I merge these 2 radios into a single checkbox, which toggles these values? Appreciate any help.

Here is what the JS looks like right now:

```
    $(function() {
      const memberButtons = {
          Agree: $('#agreeMembershipRadio'),
          DisAgree: $('#skipMembershipRadio')
        },
        chkBox = $('<input type=checkbox id="skipMembershipCheckbox">').appendTo(memberButtons.Agree.parent().parent());
      chkBox.parent().append('<label for="skipMembershipCheckbox" class="labelcheck"><span class="checktext">Jeg er/vil bli medlem av Norli-klubben og får medlemsrabatt på et stort utvalg av varer.</span></label><span><a href="#" class="action show-terms-popup" data-bind="if: isTermsAvailable"><span>Se vilkår.</span></a><span data-bind="ifnot: isTermsAvailable"></span><span>Fullfør registering på SMS etter.</span></span>');
      memberButtons.DisAgree[0].click();
      chkBox.change(function() {
        (this.checked ? memberButtons.Agree : memberButtons.DisAgree)[0].click();
      }).click();
      //$('.radio').hide();
    });
```

If you see 3 lines before the last, i swapped memberButtons.Agree with memberButtons.DisAgree so that when the checkbox is checked, the Agree button is selected. But i want the DisAgree to be selected on load, and checkbox unselected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging on your description, the radio buttons are still needed in the background for the page to keep working.
The solution below is very specific to this example, but should do the trick. To show the workings, I have not hidden the radio buttons, but uncommenting the last line should do just that.

NB, right now it is a one way street, the radio buttons react on the checkbox, not the other way around. But that shouldn't be a problem if the radio buttons are to be hidden.

```js
$(function(){
    const memberButtons = {Agree : $('#agreeMembershipRadio'), DisAgree:$('#skipMembershipRadio') },
    chkBox = $('<input type=checkbox id="skipMembershipCheckbox">').appendTo(memberButtons.Agree.parent().parent());
  chkBox.parent().append('<label for="skipMembershipCheckbox"><span>Jeg er/vil bli medlem av klubben</span></label>');
  memberButtons.DisAgree.click();
  chkBox.change(function(){
    (this.checked ? memberButtons.Agree : memberButtons.DisAgree).click();
  });
  
  //uncomment this to hide the radio buttons
  //$('.radio').hide();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="bember-register">
        <h3>
            <span>Bli medlem og få medlemspris!</span>
        </h3>
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="bember-register" id="agreeMembershipRadio" data-bind="checked: isRegister, checkedValue: 1" value="1" checked="checked">
            <label for="agreeMembershipRadio">
                <span>
                    <span>Jeg er/vil bli medlem av klubben og får medlemsrabatt på et stort utvalg av varer.</span>
                </span>
            </label>
            <span>
                <a href="#" class="action show-terms-popup" data-bind="if: isTermsAvailable">
                    <span>Se vilkår.</span>
                </a>
                <span data-bind="ifnot: isTermsAvailable"></span>
                <span>Fullfør registering på SMS etter kjøp.</span>
            </span>
        </div>
        <div class="radio">
            <input type="radio" name="bember-register" id="skipMembershipRadio" data-bind="checked: isRegister, checkedValue: 0" value="0">
            <label for="skipMembershipRadio">
                <span>
                    <span>Jeg vil ikke bli medlem av klubben.</span>
                </span>
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to help. Visually it's working as I wanted it to. But it's not changing the selection in the back-end :/. Plus one more thing, can you change so that the checkbox is unchecked on load? The rest is correct! I will send you a test link in a minute (uploading your code through third party code injection software on a test platform).

Comment: https://norli.convert.no/checkout/cart/?test=test

Just add something to the cart and go to that link.

Comment: Looks like it is updated on the radiobutton change event (or something related), which doesn't fire on setting `checked` programmatically.  I have changed the code to `click()` instead, to have the chain fire. Should still work with the buttons hidden. Can you try that variant?

Comment: You're a king! It seems like it's working. I'm gonna upload the code to test now so you can see. But one last thing, is it safe to use the code I made above to make it select the no-thanks option on load? Or do you have a better more consistent solution than that?

Comment: In the test page I see now the 'No thanks'  option is already selected?

Comment: Yea no thanks is selected but only in the front end. If you click it you see that it loads and selects it. It remembers your last choice, so if you select yes, then reload the page, it could appear thst no thanks is selected but it's actually not(in the back end).

Comment: Ah, it should work then by `click`ing programatically. You can do both the new checkbox and have it trigger the underlying click() on the radiobutton at the same time, by calling click() on the checkbox after binding the `change`. I have updated the code to reflect just that (chaining the click after the change, the default html for the checkbox is off)

Comment: You're awesome. I really appreciate the help. How did u become so good in js? I'm interested in learning more. It's fun when things actually work  I'll try it when I get home! Thanks a bunch

Comment: I just checked, it works but it is clicking the wrong radio on load. The bottom radio should be clicked on load. So on load: Bottom radio "Jeg vil ikke bli medlem av klubben" should be checked, and checkbox should be unchecked. I will edit my post and show u what my JS looks like right now, I changed one thing on the end of the code because it was checking the checkbox together with the no-thanks radio so I just had to reverse it. Can you make it so it clicks the other radio? Then it will be perfect!

Comment: Ah, the current checkbox text does not correspond with its goal? 'jeg vil ikke'  If it needs to be the other way around, the checkbox can simply have 'checked=true'  during creation and the click() will then trigger turning it off. But easier to just call the radio button click (`memberButtons.DisAgree.click()`) and leave the checkbox click altogether

Comment: Awesome, I updated my code and changed ```memberButtons.DisAgree[0].checked = true;``` to ```memberButtons.DisAgree[0].click()``` now it's both checked and clicked on load on the correct one. Thanks a lot for all your help. Marking it as a solution =D